# Regular expression in power shell to convert character between double quotes to upper case

Tags: regex, powershell

I want to write a powershell script which will convert a string which is present between double quotes in a file, and convert it into upper case.
The files are placed in different folders.

I am able to extract the string between the double quotes and convert it to upper case, but not able to replace it in the correct position.

Ex : This is the input string.

```
"e" //&&'i&&
```

The output should be

```
"E" //&&'i&&
```

This is what i have tried. Also this even i not replacing the content of the file.

```
 $items = Get-ChildItem * -recurse
# enumerate the items array
foreach ($item in $items)
{
      # if the item is a directory, then process it.
     if ($item.Attributes -ne "Directory")
     {  
        (Get-Content $item.FullName ) |          

         Foreach-Object { 
            if (($_ -match '\"'))
            {                           
                $str = $_

                $ext = [regex]::Matches($str, '".*?"').Value -replace '"'
                $ext = $ext.ToUpper()
                Write-Host $ext
                $_ = $ext
            }
            else { }            
         } |         
         Set-Content $item.FullName
     }
}
```

Comment: You need to use something like `$ext = [regex]::Replace($str, '"[^"]*"', {  param($m) $m.Value.ToUpper() })`, but you do not need the `if (($_ -match '\"'))` condition.

Comment: Hi @WiktorStribiżew, with the above change, the file is not getting updated with upper case, and it is just printing as below.

[regex]::Replace  "e" //&&'i&& "[^"]*"  param($m) $m.Value.ToUpper()

Comment: are the only two double quotes the ones around the letter you want to make upper case? if so, you can split on the quotes, `.ToUpper()` the item, and the `-join` them back with the appropriate quotes.

Comment: Did you set the `$ext` variable?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, yes the only characters between the double quotes should be converted to upper case.

Comment: I tested with `$str  = '"abc" and "rtg"'` and `[regex]::Replace($str, '"[^"]*"', { param($m) $m.Value.ToUpper() })` prints `"ABC" and "RTG"`

Comment: Yes, I am also able to see the prints in which the characters are converted to upper case, but the existing file contents are not getting updated or overwritten. Am i missing something here ?

Comment: I am using a bat file to run the powershell script and both are in the same folder.

@ECHO OFF
SET ThisScriptsDirectory=%~dp0
SET PowerShellScriptPath=%ThisScriptsDirectory%test.ps1
PowerShell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command "& '%PowerShellScriptPath%'";

cmd /k
PAUSE

Answer (score 0):

This can do it. Really I wasn't following your code so I stripped it and modified the regex.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem "C:\Users\UsernameHere\Desktop\Folder123\*.txt"
# enumerate the items array
foreach ($item in $items){
      # if the item is a directory, then process it.
     if ($item.Attributes -ne "Directory"){  
        $content = (gc $item.FullName ) 
        $content = $content.replace('"\w.*"',$matches[0].ToUpper)
        $content | sc $item
     }
 }
```

Comment: The [`System.String.Replace`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.String.Replace) method performs _literal_ substring replacements, not regex-based ones. `$Matches` is an automatic _PowerShell_ variable that is unrelated to .NET method calls. Note that alias `sc` for `Set-Content` no longer works in PowerShell [Core] 6+.

Answer (score 0):

If you had powershell 6 or 7:

```
'"hi"' -replace '".*"', { $_.value.toupper() }

"HI"


'"e" //&&''i&&' -replace '".*"', { $_.value.toupper() }   

"E" //&&'i&&
```

Answer (score 0):

I am able to print the upper case characters with the below code, but the file is not getting updated. It still has the old characters, How to update the fie with new contents.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem *.txt -recurse
# enumerate the items array
foreach ($item in $items)
{
      # if the item is a directory, then process it.
     if ($item.Attributes -ne "Directory")
     {  
        (Get-Content $item.FullName ) |          

         Foreach-Object { 
            $str = $_
            $_ = [regex]::Replace($_, '"[^"]*"', { param($m) $m.Value.ToUpper() })
            Write-Host $_           
         } |         
         Set-Content $item.FullName 
     }
}
```

Comment: Also I have problems when converting umlaut characters to upper case.
Example : "ž" is getting replaced as Å¾

Ideally, the output should be Ž